# What do the numbers 100 T300 mean on a Ford Transit?

Tags: ford

I bought a used Ford Transit without an owner's manual, and it's marked with the

100 T300

on the side, what do they mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been several slightly different "standards" for these markings for different models, but they show the engine power and gross weight (note, the gross weight is NOT the load capacity of the van, it includes the weight of the van itself plus passengers, fuel, etc).

Most likely it means a 100bhp (or 100PS) engine and 3.0 tons (or 3,000 kg) gross weight.

Comment: Gross weight also includes things like passengers and fuel.